# WPF Window: Automatically resize/adjust elements in window when adjusting the window

Tags: c#, wpf

my problem is, that I can't figure out how this works (didn't find something useful yet here):

I have a WPF window with a few elements. When I run it, and scale it (by dragging the edge), the elements stay where they are.
I want to make, that their layout (width, height, scale, position, etc.) is adjusting automatically to the center and the scale etc. is propotional to the scale of the window. It's important to know, that it should work when the program is running!
I have no code yet.

Im sorry if this question is already answered, I didn't find anything here or on the internet itself.
Thanks for helping!

Sirion

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

It's difficult to answer this question without knowing your exact usage scenario. If you want the scale of everything to adjust then you can wrap everything in a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox>
    ... your controls go here ...
</Viewbox>
```

If you want the control sizes to stay constant, but the *layout* to change, then you can use Grids:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- will stay at required size -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- will change as window size changes -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```